# count numbers of rows present in a column in MySql with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, count, rows

I want to add a Serial No. on the first column in the MySQL table in my C# program. To do this automatically with every row entry, I need to count previous rows and '+1' with the result.
How to count numbers of rows present in a column in MySQL with C#?

This is the code I am using now:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "insert into database.accounts (idaccounts,Name,EmailID,UserID,Password,DOB,Gender) values('" +3+ "','" + this.AddUserName.Text + "','" + this.AddEmail.Text + "','" + this.AddUserID.Text + "','" + this.AddPassword.Text + "','"+this.dateTimePicker.Text + "','" + Gender + "') ;";
        MySqlConnection conData = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        MySqlCommand cmdData = new MySqlCommand(Query, conData);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conData.Open();
            myReader = cmdData.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("User Added Successfully!");
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I want to add the Serial No. in the **idaccounts** column automatically with every new entry.

Comment: Please show us how you connect to the db, so we can help you

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TABLENAME>`? Or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE NOT <COLUMNNAME> IS NULL`?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please help. @Mafii

Comment: As Grant Winney pointed out, this is not going to work when you have multiple clients using the database. Can you change the idaccounts column to use the AUTO_INCREMENT option instead? Then you don't have to insert the id. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Thanks @StephenByrne ! It really worked for me! Thank you very much.